# store in array and insert with different field names

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to store $_POST values in an array but my input fields have different names and when I insert only one field gets inserted.

Here is my php code.

```
<?php
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","invoice");

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $des = $_POST['describe'];
    $qty = $_POST['quantity'];
    $rate = $_POST['rate'];

    $array = array($des, $qty, $rate);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `product_description`(`product`, `quantity`, `rate`) VALUES ('".implode('","', $value)")";
        $conn->query($sql);
    }
} 
?>
```

I am a newbie in php language so please could anyone help me to store multiple field values in an array and run the insert query?

Comment: <?php
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","invoice");
 
  $des = $_POST['describe'];
  $qty = $_POST['quantity'];
  $rate = $_POST['rate'];
   
  $array = array($des, $qty, $rate);
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    //print_r($value);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `product_description`(`product`, `quantity`, `rate`) VALUES ('".implode('","', $value)")";
   $conn->query($sql);
  }
} 
?>

Comment: Why you need `foreach` when you use `implode`? Also, it is open to SQL injection!!!

Comment: can you update the question to add HTML so getting idea how you input values?

Comment: Seems your `$_POST` data missing check example its working fine https://eval.in/836721

Comment: <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" id="invoice_form">
 Particulars <textarea class="form-control"  placeholder="" name="describe[]"></textarea>
 Quantity <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" placeholder="" name="quantity[]">
 Rate <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" placeholder="" name="rate[]">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: just check below my answer

Comment: If you have only 3 values than just change this line  $sql = "INSERT INTO `product_description`(`product`, `quantity`, `rate`) VALUES ('".$array[0]."','".$array[1]."','".$array[2]."')";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** since your input is array so .you need to use `for` loop to get the `each row` record

**2nd :** use `prepared statement` to avoid `sql injection`

```
<?php
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","invoice");

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['describe']);$i++){

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `product_description` (`product`, `quantity`, `rate`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss',$_POST['describe'][$i],$_POST['quantity'][$i],$_POST['rate'][$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row_count = $stmt->affected_rows;

    if($row_count>0){

         echo "data inserted";

     }else{

        echo "data inserted";

      } 

   }


    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. These few things I am coming across for the first time. Gota gear up n learn deeper.

Comment: bro what actually does the ?,?,? do in the values section? could you please give a brief explanation?

Comment: I think it's better to read here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php @Armour

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using foreach try like this

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `product_description`(`product`, `quantity`, `rate`) 
          VALUES ('".$array[0]."','".$array[1]."','".$array[2]."')";
      $conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do implode or foreach. When you submit the form, and get the result by using `get` or `post`, you can see results are already in form of array.

I'll recommend you to use `bindparam`. your query is open to `sql injection`.

Try this:

```
<?php
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","invoice");
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    explode($_POST);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `product_description`(`product`, `quantity`, `rate`) VALUES ('$describe,$quantity,$rate')";
    $conn->query($sql);
 } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro.

Comment: Accept as answer if it helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST['describe'] as $key=>$row){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `product_description` (`product`, `quantity`, `rate`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss',$row,$_POST[$key]['quantity'],$_POST[$key]['rate']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row_count = $stmt->affected_rows;

    if($row_count>0){
         echo "data inserted";
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro.

Comment: Accept as answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Is there need to even put your values in an array in the first place? Just change your query to this and execute it

```
"INSERT INTO ´product_description´(´product´, ´quantity´, ´rate´) VALUES($des, $qty, $rate)";
```

Remove all that foreach and array creation statements